# How to find the disk usage total of specific files in a directory

Tags: linux, disk

So I have a directory

```
/opt/splunk/var/run/
```

So I want to get the disk usage of all the files under run directory which contains either world bundle or delta

Example :

```
ls -lrth /opt/splunk/var/run

6726763764-7937483-7237438.bundle (file)
ywueye-7274837-2829383.delta      (file)
serverclass.xml                   (file)
splunk                            (directory)
```

so I want the total disk usage of `6726763764-7937483-7237438.bundl`e and `ywueye-7274837-2829383.delta` files

is this possible?

Comment: [du -b -h /opt/splunk/var/run](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=du&category=1&russian=2) ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. If you feel the question is on-topic, then see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It should be easy to find an example on the web. This question has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 2):

try `du`. here is the example

```
du -sh *.bundl *.delta
```

for the total

```
du -sch *.bundl *.delta | grep total
```

Comment: I cannot go into the directory 

i have to do 

sudo  du -sch /opt/splunk/var/run/ | grep total

can u change ur answer to the above scenario please ?

Comment: for me in my terminal * doesnot work

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `find` for a complex search and then count the total size with `du` command:

```sh
 find /opt/splunk/var/run \( -name "*bundle*" -o -name "*delta*" \) -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

or with regex for a shorter syntax:

```sh
find /opt/splunk/var/run -regex '.*\(bundle\|delta\).*' -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

Then you can use `grep` and `awk` to pick up only the total size from the output:

```sh
 find /opt/splunk/var/run -regex '.*\(bundle\|delta\).*' -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=- | grep total | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: when i do ur command 

it is giving the erro -- you have too many ')'

moreover find is also searching files named bundle inside Splunk directory also ( from my above example)

Comment: I mean if u see my example , there is a directory called splunk inside the run.Splunk directory also have some files which contain bundle in their name.find command is listing out them also.I dont want it to go deeper than run directory .It should only consider the files whose name contain bundle or delta under run directory and give me total disk usage.

Comment: 1. I've fixed the path so it will use the correct folder from now.

2. Try the command with `-regex` instead of the `-name` option. It may be a problem with `(` in your shell.

Comment: Still it goes inside splunk directory

Comment: You can use `-maxdepth 1` option of the find comand to limit the depth. So it will look like `find /opt/splunk/var/run -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*\(bundle\|delta\).*' -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=- | grep total | awk '{ print $1 }'`

Comment: find /opt/splunk/var/run -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*\(bundle\|delta\).*' -print0 , until here it works fine.if i use the total thing , it says permission denied.because these direcorty is owned by splunk user.i cannot change to splunk user.i can only do sudo -u splunk before find.i think not changing to splunk user is the problem here.

Comment: I checked with my friend who have root password , ur command works awesome.
but is there any way we can change ur command for my situiation??

Answer (score 0):

use du command as below
du -sh * |grep *bundl*